# Can anyone help identifying this (close-up or what) lens?

Tags: lens

T-mount on one side and something strange (similar to Arri PL? on the other)?

[image: ![enter image description here]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it's actually a lens? Have you tried taking a picture with it?

Comment: I don't know if it is a lens. But has rotating ring, so could be maybe some kind of close-up part, enlarger or similar. I didn't personally try it because I cannot mount it to my equipment.

Comment: What's the diameter of the threads? If it's 44mm, then you're probably looking at a Miranda-compatible part. If it's 42mm, then what is the thread pitch (either 0.75mm (T mount), or 1mm (M42 mount)).

Comment: There's no doubt that T-mount is from one side. Bigger question is what's from the other?

Comment: Anyone with any idea?

Comment: With knurling on the barrel like that has, it appears to be military type stuff.

Comment: looks like the objective of a binocular or telescope

Comment: It certainly is a lens - might not be a camera lens though :)

Comment: It looks similar to an enlarger lens ??

Comment: Looks like a teleconverter or macro helicoid.

Comment: Can't tell the size from the photos, but if that thing is somewhere between an inch to an inch and a half in diameter, then IMO, @cmason is on the right track. The end with the four lugs is the end that you peer into, and the purpose of the four lugs is to attach a replaceable, rubber "eye cup." The other end would be threaded into the body of the _insert-name-of-optical-instrument-here_.

Answer (score 1):

Since it doesn't have any markings I doubt its a lens for any consumer camera. I thought it might have been a DIY type 3D printed lens, but the finish is way better than what I've seen come out of most 3D printers.

My top two guesses

1) Lens for a rifle scope (with some kind of eye pad attached to the other end)

2) lens for night vision binoculars.  [link](https://shop.opticsplanet.com/night-optics-1x-night-vision-objective-lens-for-generation-3-night-vision-systems.html)